# Python variable to java script variable in Tornado

Tags: python, tornado

I am having a python variable in
    {% set text = ['a', 'b', 'c'] %}

```
<script>
    var data = {{ text }}
</script>
```

I am getting java script variable as-
data = ["&#39a&#39", "&#39b&#39", "&#39c&#39"]

Comment: What's wrong with `data = ['a', 'b', 'c']`?

Comment: sorry output java script variable is coming as -  var data = [&#39;a&#39;, &#39;b&#39;, &#39;c&#39;]